# persist data in context file from local storage in React?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, use-effect, react-context, persist

I am using React context to store a variable called lesson which typically holds a number 1-7. I am trying to persist the lesson number when the page is refreshed. so far I can see that the correct number is set to local storage when I click the Link, but then I get errors due to context.lesson being undefined when I refresh Lesson.js. (The lesson variable is initially set through an event in Menu.js.) Essentially the state "lesson" is clearing/undefined on refresh.

My logic:

1. Click the Link which sets the lesson in state & local storage
2. On refresh, run a useffect that gets the local storage value, and
   sets the lesson state as that.

Menu.js

```
     <Link
        to={`/Module/${index + 1}`}
        onClick={() => {context.setLesson(index + 1);}}
     />
```

Context.js

```
  const [lesson, setLesson] = useState();
```

Lesson.js

```
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("lesson", JSON.stringify(context.lesson));
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem("lesson");
    if (data) {
      context.setLesson(JSON.parse(data));
    }
  }, []);
```

context.lesson logs as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I used a custom hook to solve my problem. moved lesson out of context, and into App.js.

```
 //initial lesson state
  const [lesson, setLesson] = useLocalStorage("lesson", "0");
  //set lesson state
  function setLessonHandler(param) {
    setLesson(param);
  }
  return (
    <AppProvider>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Menu setLesson={setLessonHandler} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/Module">
          <Lesson lesson={lesson} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </AppProvider>
```

unfortunately i cant use a server for this problem so local storage it is!